# Как определить какая кнопка была нажата?

Tags: javascript

В продолжении изучения темного мира javascript прошу помощи в таком вопросе: есть массив кнопок (по типу калькулятора)

```
<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><button>0</button>
```

нужно при нажатии на клавишу считывать значение цифры. Пробовал таким методом:

```
javascript code:

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

на что в консоли выдается ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #NodeList
> has no method 'addEventListener'

с указанием на строку

```
buttons.addEventListener('click', function(e){
```

не могу найти инфу, может просто не знаю куда копать. Я так понимаю, что он не хочет привязывать обработчик к коллекции элементов. Подскажите плз

Comment: Спросите себя, что содержится в переменной buttons: массив или элемент? А как событие привязывается на элемент?

Comment: конечно коллекция кнопок
т.е. Вы хотите сказать, что нужно сделать что-то типа

    function(event){
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
                console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
            })
        }
    }
??

Comment: и как тогда сделать, чтобы эта функция отрабатывала при клике на кнопке? на что ее вешать, на document.addEventListener?

Comment: var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log(this); // this будет указывать на кнопку
        }, false);
    }

А можно немного по другому:

    <div id='btns'>
        <button></button>
        ...
    </div>

js:

    var btns_container = document.getElementById('btns');
    
    btns_container.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
            console.log(e.target);
        } 
    }, false);

Comment: с id не хотелось бы заморачиваться, потому как кнопок много, на каждую id вешать - все равно, что через if(){}else{} каждую кнопку описывать :)
благодарю за подсказку, все получилось как Вы и товарищ #Скрыто2 подсказали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = function (){
     var k = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
     for(var i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
          k[i].onclick = function (){
                alert(this.innerHTML);
            }
}
```

А так?

Comment: так работает
т.е, я правильно понял?

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
        })
    }
    });